# MVC5 - Block Controller OutputCache for specific Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller where the class has

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```

The controller has an child action. This doesn't need anything to do with OutputCache. Is there any way to tell this action not to use the class value?

The alternatives seems to be to set the attribute on all non-child actions, or to create a separate controller for the child actions.

I'd quite happily keep the same cache settings on the child action, except that child actions don't support NoStore, so you get an error. `[OutputCache(Duration=0)]` is also invalid.

To address the point that no caching is the default, so why set this in the first place? This changes the headers the client receives from `Cache-Control: private` to

```
Cache-Control: private, no-store, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

I.e. a conforming user agent won't cache it locally. Note this is for an intranet site where someone might lose their access device, rather than an Internet site.

Comment: I think you answered your question, put an attribute on the child or move it

Answer (score 4):

`OutputCache` is an inheritable attribute. That means you can override the behavior of it when set on a controller by simply adding to one of your actions with something different. For example:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration = 60)]
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Bar()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The `Bar` action will be cached for 1 hour based on the controller-level setting, while `Foo` will be cached for just 1 minute.

That said, I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Using `NoStore = true, Duration = 0` effectively *disables* caching, so you don't really need to do anything with a child action at that point to have it not cached, as the controller specifies already that nothing inside really is going to be cached. Logically, you would rather add `OutputCache` to actions in that controller you *do* want to cache, but then at that point, disabling cache on the controller-level makes no sense: that's effectively the default anyways.

Comment: I'd quite happily keep the cache settings in the child action. The trouble is you get an error that ChildActionOnly doesn't support NoStore. I've updated the question to reflect this. Also, if you just set Duration=0 that's also invalid.

Comment: I also added something to the question as to why I'm setting this in the first place. It does change the cache headers the client recieves.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in similar situation. In my case I'm trying to register the `OutputCache` attribute as global filter and it is giving me the same error when a View includes child action. What I ended up doing is creating a custom attribute inheriting `OutputCacheAttribute`. And have it skip any actions decorated with `ChildActionOnly` attribute. Assuming all your child actions are decorated with such.

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public NoCacheAttribute()
    {
        base.NoStore = true;
        base.Duration = 0;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ChildActionOnlyAttribute), false).Any()) return;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Better yet, use `filterContext.IsChildAction` to detect child

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public NoCacheAttribute()
    {
        base.NoStore = true;
        base.Duration = 0;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction) return;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```